# Checking for null XML data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, null

I get data from XML. I need to check data and if data is null I must hide this.

How can I check?

```
  <script>
   downloadUrl("gxml.php", function(data) {
       var xml = data.responseXML;
       var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
       for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
         var oid = markers[i].getAttribute("objectid");
         var status = markers[i].getAttribute("status");
         var title = markers[i].getAttribute("title");
         var volume = markers[i].getAttribute("volume");
         var kwh = markers[i].getAttribute("kwh");
         var puser = markers[i].getAttribute("puser");
         var ucomp = markers[i].getAttribute("ucomplate");
         var udate = markers[i].getAttribute("udate");
         var suser = markers[i].getAttribute("suser");
         var scomp = markers[i].getAttribute("scomplate");
         var sdate = markers[i].getAttribute("sdate");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
         var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
             parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
             parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
         var html = "ObjectID:"  + oid + "  <br/> Title:"  + title +"  <br/>Status:" + status + "  <br/>Volume:" + volume + "  <br/> KWh:" + kwh + "  <br/>User:" + puser + "  <br/> User Date:" + udate + "  <br/> User Complate :" + ucomp + "  <br/>Super user:" + suser + "  <br/> S .User Date:" + sdate + "  <br/> S. User Complate :" + scomp + "<br/> <a href=\"edit.php\">Add/Edit</a>";

</script>

// this data i get from xml. i`m need to chek this null or not null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do a `if (!myVariable)` check on any given variable. If that returns true (that is to say if the code enters the `if` body, then the data is null. What I would do is instead of doing this:

```
var oid = markers[i].getAttribute("objectid");
// ...
..."ObjectID:"  + oid + "
```

Include your title in the variable, like this:

```
var oid = markers[i].getAttribute("objectid");
if (oid) {
    oid = "ObjectID: " + oid;
}
```

and that way you can add `oid` directly to your string. If the value is null, adding it will have no effect because the variable will be empty. If there was a value, then the title will be appended and doing a `+ oid` will append the title and value at the same time.

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider marking this as the response if it helped you out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !foo ) {
    // foo is not set, it is null.
}
```